# Приведение типов С#

Tags: c#

Осваиваю C# и немного запутался с механизмом приведения типов.

```
internal class Employee{    }
internal class ExtendedEmployee : Employee{    }
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ExtendedEmployee exE = new ExtendedEmployee();
        Employee e = exE as Employee;
        Console.WriteLine(e.GetType());      
    }
}
```

По логике, должно возвращать тип `Employee`, однако выводит, что у `е` тип `ExtendedEmployee`. Что я понял не так? Явное приведение (`Employee`) тоже

Comment: Если Вас устраивает полученный ответ, пожалуйста, примите его — галка рядом с ответом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция `GetType()` возвращает реальный, динамический тип объекта по ссылке. Статический тип вам не интересен: вы его и так знаете.

Выражение `exE as Employee` не меняет сам объект, меняется лишь статический тип **ссылки**. Обе ссылки `e` и `exE` указывают на один и тот же объект динамического типа `ExtendedEmployee`.

Comment: Спасибо, суть уловил.

Comment: @ValterScott: Пожалуйста!